# Part of flatbuffers data to json

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

Having binary data of serialized object `monster`, where `monster` type is:

```
 table Monster {
      name:string;
      color:Color;
      weapon:Weapon;       <--- serialize to json only this, discard other properties
}
```

**can I directly transform only `weapon`to json and discard other fields?**

*Note my binary data is of type `Monster`. It seems like the only way to serialize `weapon` is to build separate `Weapon` object from `monster->weapon` by recursively copying all properties and then calling json serialization functions.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Compile you fbs file with `--gen-object-api`
2. This will produce `WeaponT` class and other `*T` classes
3. Use `monster->weapon()->UnpackTo(..)` method to populate `WeaponT` instance
4. Run `Weapon::Pack(fbb, &weaponT)` to serialize back on a new fbb object
5. Run `GenerateText` on fbb object created in a last step

Comment: Is this pack api creating a copy of sub buffer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Weapon can be a string object instead of Weapon object. This string can be interpreted as a JSON.
2. OR put a byte array as type of Weapon, to put any binary file stream.
3. OR better use a flex-buffer in place of json for ease of json but still better efficiency.

Or if you don't want to change your schema, and still want weapon as json:

1. Convert the complete fb data into json using json conversion utility provided by flatc.
2. Just pick  parse the weapon Node out of the complete json for your use.

Answer (score 0):

The function `GenerateText` that converts binary to JSON currently takes a buffer pointer, and not a root, so wouldn't work for your use case. However, such a function can easily be created if you have a look at the implementation of that function.

Easier maybe is the new "mini reflection" functionality (see comments and functions is `minireflect.h`). This will allow you to generate JSON from any FlatBuffers table, without even needing the schema parser.

Comment: Do you mean `flatbuffers::FlatBufferToString()`? This function is producing simplified json and I need valid json string

Comment: @MichalWegorek yes that is the "mini reflection" version. What specifically do you need it to output differently? It may be easy to add.

Comment: I need to serialize to a valid json. Note, function above produces invalid json.